rewrite old sql but result of two sql is not the same
I want to rewrite old sql
select *  from a, b, c where a.columnA = b.columnB and a.columnC *= c.columnD and a.columnE *= c.columnF
I tried as below
select * from a join b on a.columnA = b.columnB left join c on a.columnC = c.columnD left join c on a.columnE = c.columnF
but result of two sql is not the same.
Please help.

Combine the two left join columns into a single left join clause, eg:
select * 
from   a

join   b 
on     a.columnA = b.columnB

left
join   c 
on     a.columnC = c.columnD
and    a.columnE = c.columnF

